# Python Bold Text

Tags: python, text, bold

I tried to print bold text by using

```
    print('\033[1m' + 'HELP MENU' + '\033[0m')
```

However, the result was

```
    [1mHELP MENU[0m
```

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: print('\033[1m' + 'HELP MENU' + '\033[0m')

Comment: Where are you running this code and viewing the output?

Comment: PyCharm works, bu it doesn't work on python shell.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is just a little typo in the ending of the print statement. The correct code to put at the end is '\033[0m'

The full print line should look like this:

```
print('\033[1m' + 'HELP MENU' + '\033[0m')
```

Comment: I am sorry. I had typo in the question, not in the code. My actual code is written code just like yours. But, I still have that error.

Comment: @PaulKim I just ran the line of code in terminal, PyCharm, and repl.it and am not encountering the same error you are. Where are you running your code? Could you attach the exact code or a screenshot of it and the result?

Comment: It works on PyCharm. However, when I execute .py file with python shell, I get the problem.

Comment: I have added picture to clarify! Please check it.

Comment: @PaulKim In regular programming, there is no such thing as "bold text." What happens when you try to print bold text is the program that is printing the text, recognizes the special characters and displays the sting in "bold." However, if the program you are using to run the code is not capable/configured to recognize the special characters it will just treat them as a string. This is why it works in PyCharm because it is made to recognize those special characters.